# Vuex, Vuexfire: How to get data from firestore into frontend?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, vuefire

I have some data in a firestore and want to display it in my vue app.

Firestore:
[image]

Test.vue

```
<template>
  <p>{{ items }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: mapState(["items"]),

  methods: {
    getItems() {
      this.$store.dispatch("bindItems");
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getItems();
  },
};
</script>
```

index.js

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";

import { firestoreAction } from "vuexfire";
import { vuexfireMutations } from "vuexfire";

import { db } from "./db";

const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      items: [],
    };
  },

  actions: {
    bindItems: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef }) => {
      return bindFirestoreRef("items", db.collection("items"));
    }),
  },

  mutations: {
    ...vuexfireMutations,
  },

  getters: {
    items(state) {
      return state.items;
    },
  },
});

store.subscribe((state) => console.log(state));

export default store;
```

To check my store, I added this line in `index.js`: `store.subscribe((state) => console.log(state));`. As it turns out, the data from firestore actually makes it to my store:
[image]

Why is it not rendered in the frontend? What do I have to change to make it appear?

---

Edit.
When I hardcode some data in my store and remove `this.$store.dispatch("bisndItems");` from the monuted hook, the data gets rendered:

```
state() {
  return {
    items: {"name": "peter"},
  };
},
```

[image]

Comment: In order to investigate why the data from Firestore is not being shown, I would need to see the content of the HTML file.

Comment: Only the first 3 lines in `Test.vue` (`<template><p>{{ items }}</p></template>`) is html (apart from the frame in `App.vue`). Or do you mean the final rendered and shown html?

Comment: Could you please try to change "state" to contain only one hardcoded element and check if it is rendeder? If not we will investigate further.

Comment: It actually renders like this, as expected. I added this to the question above!

Comment: I believe you would like to get all documents data from the collection "items". In this [documentation](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/querying.html#one-time-read) there is an example that could be useful.

Comment: This doc is about one time reads - I'd prefer a syncronization. Besides, I think the data is successfully queried and arrives in vuex, just no in the frontend.